# Why doesnt my query insert the data into the database?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

**EDIT: Seems to be something with the database. We cant figure out what it is.**

Im having a problem with storing data thats been put into the forms. I tested the query in MS SQL (we have to use that for school) but it doesnt seem to work once i put in my variables. So im guessing the problem comes from the variables. However im not sure about that because when i echo the $_POST variables it outputs strings like i want it to. But when i put it in the query it just wont store rit in my database. Would be great if someone could help me out with this.

HTML code:

```
<form action="registerSystem.php" method="post">
Email:
<input type="email" name="emailAdres" required> <br>
Naam:
<input type="text" name="naamGebruiker" required> <br>
Wachtwoord:
<input type="password" name="wachtwoordGebruiker" required> <br>
Herhaal wachtwoord:
<input type="password" name="bevestigWachtwoord" required> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Registreer">
</form>
```

Php code:

```
require "connect.php";

session_start();

GLOBAL $conn;

function createAccount(){

$email = $_POST['emailAdres'];
$username = $_POST['naamGebruiker'];
$wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoordGebruiker'];
GLOBAL $conn;

$hashed_pass = md5($wachtwoord);
$paypal = $email;
$subscription_start = date("Y:m:d");
$land = 'Nederland';

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Customer (customer_mail_adress, name,  paypal_account, subscription_start, subscription_end, password, country_name) "
                                               ."VALUES (:customer_mail_adres, :naam, :paypal, :subscription_start, null, :password, :country_name)");

$query->bindParam(':customer_mail_adres', $email);
$query->bindParam(':naam', $username);
$query->bindParam(':paypal', $paypal);
$query->bindParam(':subscription_start', $subscription_start);
$query->bindParam(':password', $hashed_pass);
$query->bindParam(':country_name', $land);
$conn->query($query);

}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        //password check
        if ($_POST['wachtwoordGebruiker'] == $_POST['bevestigWachtwoord']) {

            createAccount();
            header("location: loginSystem.php");

        } else {

            echo "De opgegeven wachtwoorden komen niet overeen!";


    }
}?>
```

Comment: session_start() should be at the top of the page

Comment: it doesnt matter if i put it at the top or not because its about not inserting data into the database. The sessions work fine once they are logged in. Thanks for looking into it anyway:)

Comment: @coder `session_start` doesn't necessarily need to be at the very top of the page unless `require 'connect.php'` prints anything. But best practice is to have `session_start` at the very top of any page which includes it.

Comment: @Perumal93 the conn variable is just to perform queries.  Works fine on the login part but doesnt work on the register part.

Comment: @MatthieuKuivenhoven You don't need to make the variable `$conn` global explicitly when it is already defined in the global context.

Comment: can you try change `$conn->query($query);` to `$conn->execute($query);`

Comment: Do you work with two identities on this topic? Did you do any debugging to see what part of the code gets executed and which part doesn't?

Comment: @thelegend_27 are you getting any error?

Comment: try $query->execute(); instead of $conn->query($query);

Comment: Ive  tried alot of debugging. When we echo the  variables just before we execute the query (execute() or query() doesnt seem to make the difference) it echos all the input like it should. However once we put the variables in the query it doesnt insert it into our database. @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: @thelegend_27 if you could check your error log you will get the following error

` PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem is on your function.

The problem is here : `VALUES (:customer_mail_adres, :naam, :paypal, :subscription_start, null, :password, :country_name)");`

that null after `:subscription_start` is the problem, rather put a place holder in place then have a string that you will assign it value to null. then your query should work.

I'm not sure what datatype is `subscription_end` but I guess it should be date. and also use try catch block so that you can see when you have errors in your sql query. Also don't rush to reload the next page after running your query atleast but some delay on your header() so that you can print success message and see if its displaying then load next page

So this is how I updated your function.

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';



session_start();

GLOBAL $conn;

function createAccount()
{

    $email      = $_POST['emailAdres'];
    $username   = $_POST['naamGebruiker'];
    $wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoordGebruiker'];
    GLOBAL $conn;

    $hashed_pass        = md5($wachtwoord);
    $paypal             = $email;
    $subscription_start = date("Y:m:d");
    $land               = 'Nederland';
    $enddate               = 'null';


    try {

        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Customer (customer_mail_adress, name,  paypal_account, subscription_start, subscription_end, password, country_name) " . "VALUES (:customer_mail_adres, :naam, :paypal, :subscription_start, :enddate, :password, :country_name)");

        $query->bindParam(':customer_mail_adres', $email);
        $query->bindParam(':naam', $username);
        $query->bindParam(':paypal', $paypal);
        $query->bindParam(':subscription_start', $subscription_start);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $hashed_pass);
        $query->bindParam(':country_name', $land);
        $query->bindParam(':enddate', $enddate);

        if ($query->execute()) {

            echo  "Done";
        }


    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {



        echo "error". $e->getMessage();
    }



}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //password check
    if ($_POST['wachtwoordGebruiker'] == $_POST['bevestigWachtwoord']) {

        createAccount();
         header("refresh:5;url=loginSystem.php");

    } else {

        echo "De opgegeven wachtwoorden komen niet overeen!";


    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

> NB: Don't use md5(); to encrypt your passwords its no longer safe,
>   rather use php functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`
>   they are available on php.net for you to read and understand them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Customer (customer_mail_adress, name,  paypal_account, subscription_start, subscription_end, password, country_name)"
                                               ." VALUES (:customer_mail_adres, :naam, :paypal, :subscription_start, null, :password, :country_name)");

$query->bindParam(':customer_mail_adres', $email);
$query->bindParam(':naam', $username);
$query->bindParam(':paypal', $paypal);
$query->bindParam(':subscription_start', $subscription_start);
$query->bindParam(':password', $hashed_pass);
$query->bindParam(':country_name', $land);
$query->execute();
```

What I've changed here is `$conn->query($query);` to `$query->execute()`. Because you're working with prepared statements, you need to call `execute` method of the object instance of prepared statement `$query`.

`$conn->query($sql)` is commonly used when only retrieving results with `SELECT` query which doesn't contain filtering conditions that receive data from user inputs.

For your information, as a best practice, wrap up the code with `try` `catch` blocks which helps you handle the errors.

```
try {
  $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Customer (customer_mail_adress, name,  paypal_account, subscription_start, subscription_end, password, country_name)"
                                                   ." VALUES (:customer_mail_adres, :naam, :paypal, :subscription_start, null, :password, :country_name)");

  $query->bindParam(':customer_mail_adres', $email);
  $query->bindParam(':naam', $username);
  $query->bindParam(':paypal', $paypal);
  $query->bindParam(':subscription_start', $subscription_start);
  $query->bindParam(':password', $hashed_pass);
  $query->bindParam(':country_name', $land);
  $query->execute();
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage(); // or die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Before using `try` `catch` blocks, set the PDO's error reporting to exception:

`$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Set this attribute as soon as you created the `PDO` object instance.

You can also set this attribute during the object instantiation through constructor like:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo', 'root', 'password', array(
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: still doesnt work:( Seems to be the variables that are messing up the query. However when we execute the query with normal strings instead of variables it does insert the query.

Comment: You mean without using `bindParam`?

Comment: When we use the normal variables, without bindParam, it echos it fine. DIdnt test it with bindParam. We tried to replace the variables with the bindParam solution but didnt quite work out.